# How to boost::any_cast into std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have this test snippet

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

class wrapper {
  int value;
  char character;
  std::string str;

public:
  wrapper(int i, char c, std::string s) {
    value = i;
    character = c;
    str = s;
   }

  void get_data(){
    std::cout << "Value = " << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Character = " << character << std::endl;
    std::cout << "String= " << str << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(){

   std::vector<boost::any> container;
   container.push_back(10);
   container.push_back(1.4);
   container.push_back("Mayukh");
   container.push_back('A');
   container.push_back(std::bitset<16>(255) );
   wrapper wrap(20, 'M', "Alisha");
   container.push_back(wrap);

   std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(container[0]) << std::endl;
   std::cout << boost::any_cast<double>(container[1]) << std::endl;
   std::cout << boost::any_cast<std::string>(container[2]);
   std::cout << boost::any_cast<char>(container[3]) << std::endl;
   std::cout << boost::any_cast<std::bitset<16>>(container[4]);
   auto p = boost::any_cast<wrapper>(container[5]);
   p.get_data();

return 0;

}
```

In this `boost::any_cast` gives bad_casting exception for `std::string`. It means for some reason it is not able to typecast `boost::any` into `std::string`. While other classes like `bitset` or my own user defined class is working. Can you please tell me why & a way out of this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`"Mayukh"` is not a `std::string`, it is a `const` array of 7 characters `{'M', 'a', 'y', 'u', 'k', 'h', '\0'}`.  In C++14, `"Mayukh"s` is a `std::string` after `using namespace std::literals::string_literals;`.

In C++11, `std::string("Mayukh")` is a `std::string` as well.

`boost::any` only supports converting back to the exact same type (well, up to some decay/const/etc).  It does not support conversions between the types.  See [boost any documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html):

> Discriminated types that contain values of different types but do not attempt conversion between them, i.e. `5` is held strictly as an int and is not implicitly convertible either to `"5"` or to `5.0`. Their indifference to interpretation but awareness of type effectively makes them safe, generic containers of single values, with no scope for surprises from ambiguous conversions.

Augmenting `any` with extra smart conversions can be done.  For example, a pseudo-any that takes an incoming type, and possibly auto-converts it (so it won't store `short`s: it converts all signed integral types to `int64_t` and unsigned to `uint64_t`, it converts `"hello"` to `std::string("hello")`, etc) before storing it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to say "an `std::string`"?

Comment: @Columbo I'm with you on that, but there are those who pronounce it as *stood string*, in which case *a* is appropriate.

Comment: @Columbo It starts with an s, end of story. Abbreviations are _abbreviations_ not meant to be pronounced (they're _not_ acronyms). But thanks for explaining how on earth people come up with that insane juxta-position of _"an `std::T`"_ some times :)

Comment: @Columbo How do you  pronounce `std::string` to make you think it needs an `an`?

Comment: It's definitely pronounced stood string. That should be in the standard. Under [basic.obviously].

Comment: @Yakk Well, I pronounce it "s-t-d string"... :D but yeah, if in your mind it's pronounced "stood" then "a" is definitely the right article to use.

Answer (score 6):

That's because `"Mayukh"` is not a `std::string`. It's a `const char[7]`, which would decay into `const char*`:

```
boost::any a = "Mayukh";
std::cout << a.type().name() << '\n';  // prints PKc, pointer to const char
if (boost::any_cast<const char*>(&a)) {
    std::cout << "yay\n";              // prints yay
}
```

If you want to be able to use `any_cast<std::string>`, you'd need to put it in as a `std::string`:

```
container.push_back(std::string("Mayukh"));
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer to the question body but rather to the title to help others who also come here from google:

```
bool is_char_ptr(const boost::any & operand)
{
    try {
        boost::any_cast<char *>(operand);
        return true;
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_any_cast &) {
        return false;
    }
}

std::string any2string(boost::any anything)
{
    if (anything.type() == typeid(int)) {
        return std::to_string( boost::any_cast<int>(anything) );
    }
    if (anything.type() == typeid(double)) {
        return std::to_string(boost::any_cast<double>(anything));
    }
    if (is_char_ptr(anything)) {
        return std::string(boost::any_cast<char *>(anything));
    }
    if (boost::any_cast<std::string>(anything)) {
        return boost::any_cast<std::string>(anything);
    }

}
```

The last if looks weird but it works because the function is overloaded.